# Goto next ViewController right away?

Tags: ios, swift

I navigate to `LoadUserDataViewController` after a login view controller, load some user data, then automatically go to `HomeViewController`. Right now it only works if I use a button.

```
class LoadUserDataViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       //this doesn't transition to the Home View Controller
        transitionToHome()
  
    }

    //this does transition to the home view controller
    @IBAction func gotoNextVCButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        transitionToHome()
        
    }
    
    func transitionToHome() {
        
        let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `viewDidLoad` is too soon. You need to wait until `viewDidAppear`. However, if the goal is _skip_ the login view controller entirely (because the user is already logged in), this is not how to do it. You should not be wantonly changing the root view controller like this.

Comment: Have you tried `[self presentViewController: homeViewController...]` instead of playing with rootVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try performing the `transitionToHome` in `viewDidAppear` instead.

```
class LoadUserDataViewController: UIViewController {
//...
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        transitionToHome()
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can provide a delay:

```
class LoadUserDataViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        perform(#selector(transitionToHome), with: self, afterDelay: 0.5)
    }
    @objc func transitionToHome() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I was writing this at the same time dude.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked. I never knew you could completely remove ```viewDidLoad```  so I couldn't use ```viewDidAppear``` or  ```override``` properly.